# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on product page on Magento

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento, varnish

My `Magento` is acting weird since I installed Varnish. When I try to load product page I got 301 redirect to the same page with `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` on `Chrome`.

I used this tutorial do configure Varnish: `https://www.vultr.com/docs/installing-varnish-4-with-apache2-on-ubuntu-14-04`

The rest of the website is working flawless, the only problem is when I try to acesse product's page.

I found this answer to my problem: `https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/issues/660`, I also use Creare SEO, the thing is I'm using Apache2 and not nginx, and I looked everywhere but I can't find the equivalent to adding "`astcgi_param SERVER_PORT 80`" on `Apache2`.

Here is my .htaccess file:

http://pastebin.com/twRqkNK7

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: so, what is the question?

Comment: Hi. Sorry about that, how do I fix this? I'd like to properly use Varnish + Magento + Creare SEO extension on Apache2

Comment: First, you need to add your .htaccess to your question and also add request example, on which you got error.

Comment: Here is my .htaccess file: http://pastebin.com/twRqkNK7

I'm getting this problem everytime I try to acess a product page, the exact problem is explained here: https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/issues/660

This solution dosen't work for me because I'm using apache2. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem in my case is produced by creareSeo extension.
You have to disable Canonical Product Redirecting or use the following fix
https://github.com/adampmoss/CreareSEO/pull/81